# How to improve my calling of multiple JavaScript functions. Program works however I would like a smoother way of handling these functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, dom

Script works however the whole delay, (setTimeout) is clunky and I'm concerned it will not work on slow connections. There must be a better way of handling this with **only** JavaScript and jQuery right? Functions are simple such as navigating pages, clicking inputs and entering textual data.

Without the delay certain events would trigger out of order. For instance sometimes the create() function would get called before the previous functions finished.

```
 function all() {
        navigate();
        setTimeout(start, 400);
        setTimeout(pickForm, 600);
        setTimeout(addName, 900);
        setTimeout(addDescription, 1500);
        setTimeout(singleLineTextField, 2000);
        setTimeout(multiLineTextField, 2200);
        setTimeout(radioButtons, 2400);
        setTimeout(checkBoxes, 2600);
        setTimeout(dropDown, 2800);
        setTimeout(multiSelect, 3000);
        setTimeout(datePicker, 3200);
        setTimeout(smessages, 3400);
        setTimeout(fmessages, 3600);
        setTimeout(create, 3800);
        setTimeout(properties, 5000);
    }
    all();
```

Comment: What are you doing that requires so many `setTimeout` calls?

Comment: Why not just `start(); pickForm(); addName(); ...`?

Comment: There are less repetitive ways to write it, but there *shouldn't* be a need for such a thing

Comment: Assuming you can use ES7 or newer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await

Comment: Sequence them with timeout:- function timeout(t){ return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, t)) }

Comment: So:- async function all(){
navigate();
await timeout(400);
start();
await timeout(200);
pickForm();
await timeout(300);
addName();
}

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying something like chaining, 
    i.e start() function is to be executed after navigate() is completed, and pickForm to be executed after start(), you can do that with promises or callbacks.

```
//cb_func is a callback function
// receive a function -----------------
function getNewENumber( parentENumber, cb_func ){

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "",
           data: {}

             // ------v-------use it as the callback function
           success: cb_func,
            error: function(request,error) {
                alert('An error occurred');
                // console.log(request, error);
            }
    });
}

var parentENumber = E1-3;

getNewENumber(parentENumber, function( returnValue ){
    alert( returnValue );
});

hope this helps.
```